# Como tomar la variable con la fecha mas antigua - SQL SP

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

tengo un procedimiento almacenado, el cual debe tomar de un set de variables, la que contenga la fecha mas antigua en campo FECHA_CREACION

un codigo de producto esta en distintas tablas, debo tomar el dato de la tabla que tenga la fecha mas antigua  y pasarlo a la variable FECHA_MAS_ANTIGUA.

primero seteo la fecha en una variable:

```
SET FECHA_CREACION_tb1   = (SELECT FECHA_CREACION FROM PRODUCTO_tb1  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new ) ;
SET FECHA_CREACION_tb2   = (SELECT FECHA_CREACION FROM PRODUCTO_tb2   WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new ) ;
SET FECHA_CREACION_tb3   = (SELECT FECHA_CREACION FROM PRODUCTO_tb3   WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new ) ;
```

hasta allí todo bien,

pero luego necesito tomar la variable con la fecha mas alta, y es ahí en donde no logro,

lo que actualmente estoy realizando es:

```
SET FECHA_MAS_ANTIGUA = MIN(FECHA_CREACION_tb1, FECHA_CREACION_tb2, FECHA_CREACION_tb3);
```

alguien sabe como puedo tomar de un conjunto de variables el dato de fecha mas antigua y pasársela a una variable

ACTUALIZACIÓN (SOLUCIÓN):

```
SET  FECHA_MAS_ANTIGUA = (SELECT MIN(T.FECREA_PRO)
FROM (SELECT FECREA_PRO FROM TB1  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
    UNION
    SELECT FECREA_PRO FROM TB2  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
    UNION
    SELECT FECREA_PRO FROM TB3  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
    UNION
    SELECT FECREA_PRO FROM CTB4  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
    UNION
    SELECT FECREA_PRO FROM TB5 WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
) T);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla podría ser usando una subconsulta uniendo las tres consultas que tienes de la siguiente forma:

```
SET FECHA_MAS_ANTIGUA = (SELECT MIN(T.FECHA_CREACION)
    FROM (SELECT FECHA_CREACION FROM PRODUCTO_tb1  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
        UNION
        SELECT FECHA_CREACION FROM PRODUCTO_tb2  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
        UNION
        SELECT FECHA_CREACION FROM PRODUCTO_tb3  WHERE CODIGO_PRO = codigo_new
    ) T);
```

Comment: ok patricio, voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: patricio no me realizaba el proceso con select, pero si me sirvió la sintaxis tuya. finalmente lo deje con un set y me corrió ok. actualizo codigo arriba.